# I cannot open a SSRs RDL file in designer view. Why is this happening?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have just opened up a project that contains SSRs reports and yet I am unable to view them in Design Mode. When I click on them, only the XMLS appear and I am not sure how to resolve this in VS 2012 ?

Comment: You would need to open the project/solution associated to the report rather than the `.rdl` file itself.

Answer (score 11):

In a version of Visual Studio that includes SQL Server Report Services, create a new Report Server Project.

In the new Report Server Project, right-click the project node in the Solution Explorer and choose "Add" > "Existing Item...". Then browse to and select the RDL file. Once it is in a Report Server Project, you can right-click the report and choose "View Designer" to see it in Design View. By default, it ought to open in Design View anyway.

If the file is not part of a Report Server Project, you'll only be able to view the XML text. Depending upon the Version of Visual Studio you may (or may not) get XML highlighting and intellisense.

Comment: What versions includes Reporting Services? In 2017, I have explicitly installed Data Tools, and still do not see these options.

Answer (score 6):

Rename report as '.rdlc' it will open in design mode in Visual studio 2012

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2015:
First make sure you have installed `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools`, then rename your reports to `.rdls`, right click on reports > Open With > Report Designer

Answer (score 3):

If you are not able to create / add Report Server Project  download and install  Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 from the location [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) (if you VS is 2012). Then create an new report server [Reproting server project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vygoN.png) project Report Server Project and do as "add Existing Item" as my RDL report which need to be opened and go for design view. Then it will open the report in design mode.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing Report Template in visual studio
Got to Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features.

Select you Visual Studio Version, right click and 'Change'.

The Visual Studio Setup splashscreen should appear, Click on Modify at the bottom left, and then under 'Windows and Web Development' select Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. The Reporting option should then appear in your installed updates.

Answer (score 2):

After installing Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, you would need to install Report Viewer for Visual Studio 2017 (or which ever version you are using)... that worked for me from link below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/99b217d0-63b2-48a7-bfe0-423e56963e21/rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio-community-2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

You can force open it by `Right click` on RDL file and click on `View Designer` to see the RDL in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the needed extensions (Microsoft Reporting Services, Report Designer) installed and everything updated, what worked for me was to open the .rptproj project, and then open the needed .rdl.